# Passing values from CLR Trigger to WCF

Tags: c#, sql-server

Somehow, I couldn't find out how to properly pass the data when a new record gets inserted, am sending the first column value back to WCF. Everything works, but I couldn't pass the data. What am I missing?

CLR Trigger to call WCF:

```
public partial class Triggers
{

    public static EndpointAddress endpoint =  new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:8000/services/myservice"));
    public static WSHttpBinding httpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
    public static ServiceClient.ServiceReference1.ServiceContractClient myclient = new ServiceClient.ServiceReference1.ServiceContractClient(httpBinding, endpoint);
    public delegate void MyDelagate(String crudType);
    [SqlProcedure()]
    public static void SendData(String crudType)
    {
        myclient.UpdateOccured();//i was trying to pass the crudType value here 

    }

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlTrigger(Name = "WCFTrigger", Target = "tbCR", Event = "FOR INSERT")]
    public static void Trigger1()
    {

        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlTriggerContext myContext = SqlContext.TriggerContext;
        SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        if(myContext.TriggerAction== TriggerAction.Insert)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"context connection=true"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM tbCR", conn);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();

                //get the insert value's here
                string Name;
                Name = (string)reader[1];
                reader.Dispose();


                switch (myContext.TriggerAction)
                {
                    case TriggerAction.Update:

                         SendData(Name);

                        break;

                    case TriggerAction.Insert:

                        SendData(Name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

My Service Contract:

```
namespace SampleService
{
    class MyService : IServiceContract
    {
        public void UpdateOccured()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Update Occured");
        }

        public void InsertOccured(string Name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insert Occured",Name);
        }

    }
}
```

Interface:

```
namespace SampleService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IServiceContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void UpdateOccured();
        [OperationContract]
        void InsertOccured(string Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The contract interface explicitly specifies that `UpdateOccured` takes no parameters.

Comment: Ooops Sorry arootbeet it was suppose to be InsertOccured.

Comment: @arootbeer,changed to myclient.InsertOccured( curdType); but it throws an expception says "curdType" doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Did you figure out why it says "curdType" doesn't exist?  You should update your code sample with the changes.

Comment: @arootbeet ,no i haven't yet,still it throwing an exception at   myclient.InsertOccured(crudType );

Comment: @arootbeer finally figured it out thru http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967283/passing-values-from-sql-to-wcf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be selecting from INSERTED insertead of the actual table i.e.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM INSERTED", conn);
```

Also, you should explicitly name the columns that you need instead of using *.

INSERTED and DELETED and SQL Server created, memory-resident tables tables.

[More details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

> The deleted table stores copies of the affected rows during DELETE and
>   UPDATE statements. During the execution of a DELETE or UPDATE
>   statement, rows are deleted from the trigger table and transferred to
>   the deleted table. The deleted table and the trigger table ordinarily
>   have no rows in common.
>
> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT
>   and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new
>   rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The
>   rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger
>   table.
>
> An update transaction is similar to a delete operation followed by an
>   insert operation; the old rows are copied to the deleted table first,
>   and then the new rows are copied to the trigger table and to the
>   inserted table.

Comment: thanks amit,i seen people suggest that option using "select * from Inserted" but am not sure much about it,so i used query my actual table.please correct me if use Inserted,still the reader find the appropriate column ?

Comment: Yes like DML triggers, CLR triggers also have access to these tables Read the link I posted in the updated comment.

Comment: apart from that what am missing in my code,it not let me to pass the value @myclient.UpdateOccured(); i was trying to do myclient.UpdateOccured(crudType);

Comment: @amig_g, everything work fine now,changed my query to the suggested one by you.Now i have a question,what going to happen if there are multiple records inserted in different tables ? how the Inserted one know which table am monitoring ?

Comment: Like DML triggers you have to write one CLR trigger for each table. The one you have posted is only for table tbCR. This is specified as attribute on the method - Target = "tbCR"