# Passing values from SQL to WCF

Tags: c#

Am using CLR Trigger to pass the values to WCF,everything works fine but when try to pass the constant value its not pass thru WCF even its not throwing any exception.

**CLR Trigger**

```
public partial class Triggers
{

    public static EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:8000/services/myservice"));
    public static WSHttpBinding httpBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
    public static ServiceClient.ServiceReference1.ServiceContractClient myclient = new ServiceClient.ServiceReference1.ServiceContractClient(httpBinding, endpoint);
    public delegate void MyDelagate(String crudType);
    [SqlProcedure()]

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlTrigger(Name = "WCFTrigger",
       Target = "tbCR", Event = "FOR UPDATE, INSERT")]
    public static void Trigger1()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlTriggerContext myContext = SqlContext.TriggerContext;
        SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        if(myContext.TriggerAction== TriggerAction.Insert)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"context connection=true"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM tbCR", conn);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();

                //get the insert value's here
                string Name;
                Name = reader[1].ToString();
                reader.Dispose();
                myclient.InsertOccured(Name);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
namespace SampleService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IServiceContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void UpdateOccured();
        [OperationContract]
        void InsertOccured(String Name);
    }
}
```

**Contract**

```
namespace SampleService
{
    class MyService : IServiceContract
    {
         public void InsertOccured(string Name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insert Occured",Name);
        }

    }
}
```

every time i insert record ,WCF shows "Insert Occured" only but i was expecting "Insert Occured, Test".

Can you please guide me what i suppose to do to get the constant value from SLQ Tirgger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service operation implementation is looks like you need to add the string parameter to your Console.WriteLine() string template. In other words:

```
Console.WriteLine("Insert Occured, {0}",Name);
```

You can find more about Console.WriteLine and composite formatting here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx